# Knockout-Kendo cascading dropdownlists

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have modified the Shopping cart Knockout example (http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) to use the KendoUI DropDownLists, via the Knockout-Kendo.js library.

As shown in this jsfiddle, this is not working as expected (the second DropDownList is not populated, and appears as a standard input) . http://jsfiddle.net/L3F2Y/4/

When running this on my machine, the following javascript error is thrown:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: 'products' is undefined;
>   Bindings value: kendoDropDownList: { dataTextField: 'name', data: products, value: $parent.product }

I presume that this is happening due to the way that the Knockout-Kendo custom binding processes the collections, but any further attempts to understand/resolve this problem have been unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo DropDownList is not setup to track selected objects natively.  It wants to populate the value with a primitive.  So, it will end up just doing a `.toString()` on an object.

You would need to track the name of the category and the name of the product separately and create computed observables to keep a copy of the related object.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/e3cTT/

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I'm trying to combine your solution here (which works well for the basic shopping cart example) with this jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/adNuR/664/ - which demonstrates preloading rows from a json file. I'm getting this error - "Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option". I'm not passing any values into the computed properties (category, product) however. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be this part: `self.category.subscribe(function() {
        self.productName(undefined);
    });`  Make sure that it is `productName` and not `product`.  Otherwise, do you have a fiddle with your current progress.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. Thanks a heap!